# Use jQuery to construct "Tweet" button

Tags: php, jquery, twitter

I know how to use the "Tweet" button and to put default text into it but has anyone got anyideas how to do something like this: I have a div on my website in which i load dynamic movie quotes into, so i'd like a tweet button underneath which would tweet "(The current movie quote) and i found it here (my site URL)". Is this going to be possible or not? Could i use jQuery or have to use PHP?

Comment: the easy way is to do it right out of PHP, altering the tweet button to send that specific message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery to find the text within the movie quote div. Then construct the URL with that text before you either open a new window or change the current browser window to go to that Twitter URL.

I think the URL format to pre-fill the tweet is: http://twitter.com/home?status=here+is+my+tweet